# How can i add padding vector file in android

Tags: android, vector

How can i add paddingleft,Right,Top and bottom veriable in my vector file.

I changed

> android:viewportWidth

and

> android:viewportHeight

But Nothing change

**My Vector**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="31.416dp"
    android:height="31.416dp"
    android:viewportWidth="31.416"
    android:viewportHeight="31.416">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M28.755,6.968l-0.47,0.149L25.782,7.34l-0.707,1.129l-0.513-0.163L22.57,6.51l-0.289-0.934L21.894,4.58l-1.252-1.123
l-1.477-0.289l-0.034,0.676l1.447,1.412l0.708,0.834L20.49,6.506l-0.648-0.191L18.871,5.91l0.033-0.783l-1.274-0.524l-0.423,1.841
l-1.284,0.291l0.127,1.027l1.673,0.322l0.289-1.641l1.381,0.204l0.642,0.376h1.03l0.705,1.412l1.869,1.896l-0.137,0.737
l-1.507-0.192l-2.604,1.315l-1.875,2.249l-0.244,0.996h-0.673l-1.254-0.578l-1.218,0.578l0.303,1.285l0.53-0.611l0.932-0.029
l-0.065,1.154l0.772,0.226l0.771,0.866l1.259-0.354l1.438,0.227l1.67,0.449l0.834,0.098l1.414,1.605l2.729,1.605l-1.765,3.372
l-1.863,0.866l-0.707,1.927l-2.696,1.8l-0.287,1.038c6.892-1.66,12.019-7.851,12.019-15.253
C31.413,12.474,30.433,9.465,28.755,6.968z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M17.515,23.917l-1.144-2.121l1.05-2.188l-1.05-0.314l-1.179-1.184l-2.612-0.586l-0.867-1.814v1.077h-0.382l-2.251-3.052
v-2.507L7.43,8.545L4.81,9.012H3.045L2.157,8.43L3.29,7.532L2.16,7.793c-1.362,2.326-2.156,5.025-2.156,7.916
c0,8.673,7.031,15.707,15.705,15.707c0.668,0,1.323-0.059,1.971-0.137l-0.164-1.903c0,0,0.721-2.826,0.721-2.922
C18.236,26.357,17.515,23.917,17.515,23.917z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M5.84,5.065l2.79-0.389l1.286-0.705l1.447,0.417l2.312-0.128l0.792-1.245l1.155,0.19l2.805-0.263L19.2,2.09l1.09-0.728
l1.542,0.232l0.562-0.085C20.363,0.553,18.103,0,15.708,0C10.833,0,6.474,2.222,3.596,5.711h0.008L5.84,5.065z
M16.372,1.562
l1.604-0.883l1.03,0.595l-1.491,1.135l-1.424,0.143l-0.641-0.416L16.372,1.562z
M11.621,1.691l0.708,0.295l0.927-0.295
l0.505,0.875l-2.14,0.562l-1.029-0.602C10.591,2.526,11.598,1.878,11.621,1.691z" />
</vector>
```

**Like that**

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

wrap your path tags with group tag. then and add attribute scaleX, scaleY, pivotX and pivotY in group tag to create padding effect. like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <group
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M3,4L3,1h2v3h3v2L5,6v3L3,9L3,6L0,6L0,4h3zM6,10L6,7h3L9,4h7l1.83,2L21,6c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12c0,1.1 -0.9,2 -2,2L5,22c-1.1,0 -2,-0.9 -2,-2L3,10h3zM13,19c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5 -5,-5 -5,2.24 -5,5 2.24,5 5,5zM9.8,14c0,1.77 1.43,3.2 3.2,3.2s3.2,-1.43 3.2,-3.2 -1.43,-3.2 -3.2,-3.2 -3.2,1.43 -3.2,3.2z"/>
    </group>

</vector>
```

*pivot values depends on size of width and height of your vector

Comment: not working for me, heres my vector drawable 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mIXKUU9R1tRDR0bGI2NlY3OFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: more info on this: `scaleX` and `scaleY` define how much of the original size the drawable will have. if both are set to `0.85` for example, the image will be 15% smaller. however, it won't auto-adjust to the center when you make it smaller, so that's when you use `pivotX` and `pivotY` to add an offset on each axis.

Comment: Just to add, if you wish to center the image in the viewport, just put pivotX and pivotY values equal to half of viewportHeight and viewportWidth values. So if viewport is 24.0, put pivot as 12.0 to center the icon.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you Stefanus and all who have contributed comments to this solution. Helped me resize my vector icon! Just a quick note, if you want the resized vector to remain centered, use pivotX and pivotY values half the size of the width and height, respectively. For example, if your width and height are both 24dp, use 12dp for the pivotX and pivotY values.

Comment: hi, why viewportHeight not equal to height?

Answer (score 33):

Well `scaleX` and `ScaleY` works, but I found it difficult to align via `android:pivotX` and `android:pivotY`, so this is what I did:

Create a new xml `drawable` file, like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="15dp" android:left="15dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="15dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_image_or_icon"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: It's not necessary a new drawable if you put your vector element inside the item element.

Comment: It raised `Resources$NotFoundException` For APIs below API level 21.

Answer (score 15):

`inset` can be used starting from API level-21

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="16dp"
    android:insetTop="16dp"
    android:insetRight="16dp"
    android:insetBottom="16dp">

    <vector
        // ....... my vector
    </vector>

</inset>
```

Another option to cover APIs below level-21 to use  with `android:translateX` & `android:translateY`.. And adjust a proper `android:width` & `android:height` of the vector.

To add padding to the right/bottom use negative values for `android:translateX` & `android:translateY`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <group android:translateX="-3" 
           android:translateY="2">

        <path
            android:fillColor="#B72B579A"
            android:pathData="M18,16.08c-0.76,0 -1.44,0.3 -1.96,0.77L8.91,12.7c0.05,-0.23 0.09,-0.46 0.09,-0.7s-0.04,-0.47 -0.09,-0.7l7.05,-4.11c0.54,0.5 1.25,0.81 2.04,0.81 1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3s-1.34,-3 -3,-3 -3,1.34 -3,3c0,0.24 0.04,0.47 0.09,0.7L8.04,9.81C7.5,9.31 6.79,9 6,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3c0.79,0 1.5,-0.31 2.04,-0.81l7.12,4.16c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.61 1.31,2.92 2.92,2.92 1.61,0 2.92,-1.31 2.92,-2.92s-1.31,-2.92 -2.92,-2.92z" />
    </group>

</vector>
```

Comment: Translate is way to go!

Answer (score 6):

Create a new drawable file, add a layer-list and wrap your vector image inside item block.
like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp">
    <vector
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:viewportWidth="512"
        android:viewportHeight="512">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#4086f4"
            android:pathData="m451,135 l-105,-30 -30,-105h-210c-24.853,0 -45,20.147 -45,45v422c0,24.853 20.147,45 45,45h300c24.853,0 45,-20.147 45,-45z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#4175df"
            android:pathData="m451,135v332c0,24.853 -20.147,45 -45,45h-150v-512h60l30,105z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#80aef8"
            android:pathData="m451,135h-105c-16.5,0 -30,-13.5 -30,-30v-105c3.9,0 7.8,1.5 10.499,4.501l120,120c3.001,2.699 4.501,6.599 4.501,10.499z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff5f5"
            android:pathData="m346,241h-180c-8.291,0 -15,-6.709 -15,-15s6.709,-15 15,-15h180c8.291,0 15,6.709 15,15s-6.709,15 -15,15z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff5f5"
            android:pathData="m346,301h-180c-8.291,0 -15,-6.709 -15,-15s6.709,-15 15,-15h180c8.291,0 15,6.709 15,15s-6.709,15 -15,15z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff5f5"
            android:pathData="m346,361h-180c-8.291,0 -15,-6.709 -15,-15s6.709,-15 15,-15h180c8.291,0 15,6.709 15,15s-6.709,15 -15,15z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff5f5"
            android:pathData="m286,421h-120c-8.291,0 -15,-6.709 -15,-15s6.709,-15 15,-15h120c8.291,0 15,6.709 15,15s-6.709,15 -15,15z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#e3e7ea"
            android:pathData="m256,421h30c8.291,0 15,-6.709 15,-15s-6.709,-15 -15,-15h-30z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#e3e7ea"
            android:pathData="m256,361h90c8.291,0 15,-6.709 15,-15s-6.709,-15 -15,-15h-90z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#e3e7ea"
            android:pathData="m256,301h90c8.291,0 15,-6.709 15,-15s-6.709,-15 -15,-15h-90z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#e3e7ea"
            android:pathData="m256,241h90c8.291,0 15,-6.709 15,-15s-6.709,-15 -15,-15h-90z" />
    </vector>
</item>
```

Comment: It raised `Resources$NotFoundException` For APIs below API level 21.

Comment: Here, you dropped this: </layer-list>

Comment: To make this answer simpler: instead of adding vector directly, reference your vector drawable using inset:

<inset android:drawable="@drawable/your_vector_drawable" />

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Inset