# android:pivotY doesnt add top-padding to my android vector drawable

Tags: android, user-interface, svg, vector

I have compactTextView with compoundDrawable.

I want to add top padding to that `compoundDrawable` which is fed by vector image (I imported svg into android studio)

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711411/311130) on how to add padding to a vector drawable

but when i try this, no padding is added:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="13dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportHeight="8.11"
    android:viewportWidth="13.44">
  <group
      android:pivotX="0"
      android:pivotY="12"
      android:scaleX="1"
      android:scaleY="1">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M6.71,8.12l-6.71,-6.7l1.42,-1.42l5.29,5.3l5.29,-5.3l1.42,1.42z"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

do I need to add anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked solution works by scaling down the path inside your VectorDrawable.

In the other example the `viewPortWidth` and `viewportHeight` were 24.
The `pivotX` and `pivotY` are the origin for the transform. It's equivalent to `transform-origin` in CSS.  So thus setting the `scaleX` and `scaleY` to 0.5, results in their icon scaling down from 24x24 to 12x12, with the centre at the pivot point (12,12).

Thus you end up with a 12x12 icon in the middle of a 24x24 VectorDrawable. Thus creating a padding of 6 around the entire thing.

In your icon you have the scale attributes set to 1.  So no scaling will happen, and you won't create any padding.

Are you sure you want to create padding space in your icon?  The normal way to introduce padding is via your layout. For instance with `android:layout_marginTop` or `android:paddingTop`. I recommend you consider that approach first.

If you really do want to adjust your VectorDrawable.  Then what you want to do to create padding only at the top, is to scale the shape down towards the bottom of the icon.

So have your pivot point at the bottom of the icon:

```
  android:pivotX="0"
  android:pivotY="8.11"
```

and scale down by an appropriate amount

```
  android:scaleX="0.5"
  android:scaleY="0.5"
```

Here we are scaling down toward the bottom left of the icon, so we are therefore also going to create padding on the right. Because we are also scaling in the X direction.  You could counter that by reducing the `width` and `viewportWidth`.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="7dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="6.72"
    android:viewportHeight="8.11">
  <group
      android:pivotX="0"
      android:pivotY="8.11"
      android:scaleX="0.5"
      android:scaleY="0.5">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M6.71,8.12l-6.71,-6.7l1.42,-1.42l5.29,5.3l5.29,-5.3l1.42,1.42z"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

You could also prevent the extra padding on the right by leaving `scaleX` at "1", but that will result in your icon having the appearance of being squashed vertically.

**The translation approach**

Another approach would be just to move the icon vertically downwards, to create space at the top, instead of scaling it in size.  This has the advantage that you can more explicitly set the padding you want.

You do that by using the `translateY` attibute.  Obviously that means that the height of the VectorDrawable has to change also. So you have to handle that by adjusting the `viewportHeight`.

In the example below, I have added a vertical padding of 4, mening the viewport height of the icon goes from 8.11 to 12.11.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="13dp"
    android:height="12dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="13.44"
    android:viewportHeight="12.11">
  <group
      android:translateY="4">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M6.71,8.12l-6.71,-6.7l1.42,-1.42l5.29,5.3l5.29,-5.3l1.42,1.42z"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

If you do this, you may also need to adjust the `android:width` and/or `android:height`. 
 You can choose to either:

- increase the `android:height` as well to match the extra padding (ie to "12"), or
- keep the height at 8, and adjust the width down to compensate (eg "9").