# How to make the canvas not square?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector image in my android app:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:height="800dp"
    android:viewportWidth="21"
    android:viewportHeight="21">
  <path
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:pathData="m4.5,7.5h12"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
  <path
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:pathData="m4.498,10.5h11.997"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
  <path
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:pathData="m4.5,13.5h11.995"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"
      android:strokeLineCap="round"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

I want to make the canvas look like the following:

[image]

Decreasing `viewportWidth` makes the icon get shifted on the right side. Changing `width` also doesn't change the canvas size.

**So is there any way to trim the canvas on the sides?**

Comment: No, but you can add padding on both sides so a rectangle is drawn.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527399/how-can-i-add-padding-vector-file-in-android